# how to get sql reporting server working 2019

Tags: reporting-services

My SQL reporting server was working for a while but just recently, the reporting server web portal has stopped working and I get the following error shown in the pictures attached. I have also checked the SQL reporting server manager but for some reason, it can't find the instance name..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxIE6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyKLX.png)

Comment: Are the SQL Server and SSRS service running?

Comment: Check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8327b962-2040-4097-bb70-86815699d8bc/cannot-connect-to-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices